# Why doesn't $ always match to an end of line

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Below is a simple code snippet that demonstrates the seemingly buggy behavior of end of line matching ("$") in .Net regular expressions.  Am I missing something obvious?

```
        string input = "Hello\nWorld\n";
        string regex = @"^Hello\n^World\n";  //Match
        //regex = @"^Hello\nWorld\n";  //Match
        //regex = @"^Hello$";  //Match
        //regex = @"^Hello$World$";  //No match!!!
        //regex = @"^Hello$^World$";  //No match!!!

        Match m = Regex.Match(input, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        Console.WriteLine(m.Success);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` does not consume the newline character(s). `@"^Hello$\s+^World$"` should match.

Comment: Need to add \s* after World to get the last \n.

Comment: @gt124, I think it will match anyway, since `"^Hello$"` matches.

Comment: Aha!  Thanks for that.  It's all about the consuming part.  Thanks.

Comment: You are right. I couldn't get yours to work on my regexbuddy, then clicked on the "^$ match at line breaks" option. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` doesn't match a newline. It matches the end of the string in which the pattern is applied (unless multiline mode is enabled). There isn't much sense in having two ends in a string.

Comment: I believe it should match an end-of-line in multiline regexps (not the newline). For example in ruby, `"Hello\nWorld\n".match(/^Hello$\n^World$/m)` produces a match.

Comment: I was confused because the MSDN docs say Multiline causes ^ and $ to match the beginning and end:  "Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string."  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx